# Laravel Eloquent with JSON and looping

Tags: php, json, laravel, eloquent

I have news articles and I want to pass specific fields to a JSON.

I've tried to loop all the news with this code:

```
public function appNews() {
  $news = News::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();

  foreach($news as $newsOne) {
    $title = $newsOne->title;
    $body = $newsOne->body;
    $image = $newsOne->image;


    return response()->json([
      'title' => $title,
      'body' => $body,
      'image' => $image
    ]);

  }
}
```

But this returns one result instead of many.

If I echo the loop I get all the needed results with this code:

```
public function appNews() {
  $news = News::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();

  foreach($news as $newsOne) {
    $title = $newsOne->title;
    $body = strip_tags($newsOne->body);
    $image = $newsOne->image;

    echo '<div>' . $newsOne->title . '</div>';

    /*return response()->json([
      'title' => $title,
      'body' => $body,
      'image' => $image
    ]);*/

  }
}
```

How can I fix that with response()->json(), so I can get all the results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make one array and append it

```
public function appNews() {
  $news = News::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
  $array = [];
  foreach($news as $newsOne) {
    $title = $newsOne->title;
    $body = strip_tags($newsOne->body);
    $image = $newsOne->image;

    $array[] = [
      'title' => $title,
      'body' => $body,
      'image' => $image
    ];

  }

   return response()->json($array);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your actual code looks like this, the best way would be probably:

```
// here you select only fields you need
$news = News::select('title', 'body', 'image')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();

// here you return changed content of body by striping tags
return response()->json($news->map(function($singleNews) {
   $singleNews->body = strip_tags($singleNews->body);
   return $singleNews;
})->all());
```